# MySQL NULL AND 1 Returns NULL

Tags: mysql

I'm having this weird case where:

```
SELECT NULL AND 1;
```

Returns NULL. I'm expecting a 0 (false) here.

Is this the expected and correct behavior?

I'm on MySQL version 5.7.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected and [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) behaviour:

> Logical AND. Evaluates to 1 if all operands are nonzero and not NULL, to 0 if one or more operands are 0, otherwise NULL is returned.

Comment: Thanks! Searching for the exact operation didn't reveal this documentation :/ need to step up my searching skills!